How to add Python type annotations to a class that inherits from itself?
I'm trying add type annotations to an ElementList object that inherits from list and can contain either Element objects or other ElementGroup objects.
When I run the following code through mypy:
from typing import Self


class Element:
    pass


class ElementList(list[Element | Self]):
    pass


elements = ElementList(
    [
        Element(),
        Element(),
        ElementList(
            [
                Element(),
                Element(),
            ]
        ),
    ]
)

I get the following error:
element.py:8: error: Self type is only allowed in annotations within class definition  [misc]
Found 1 error in 1 file (checked 1 source file)

What's the recommended way to add typing annotations to this so that mypy doesn't throw an error?

To solve the error in your snippet, you can do class ElementList(list["Element | ElementList"]): .... However, your use of typing.Self indicates that you'd like the list-typed items in the list to always be upper-bounded to the class, rather than any instance of ElementList. I'm not aware of any way to specify this apart from re-declaring all the methods to also take typing.Self.

I am confused. "...inherits from list and can contain either Element objects or other ElementGroup objects." means you want to inherit from list. The behavior of a list wouldn't change depending on its content.

Your sample list argument to the ElementList constructor contains not just Elements and ElementLists but also actual lists, so a workaround of class ElementList(list["Element | ElementList"]): ... would not have worked, as @dROOOze pointed out in the comment, because list is not a subtype of ElementList.
You can work around this limitation with a type alias, which can refer to itself without creating a subtype:
class Element:
    pass

type ElementListType[T] = Element | T | list[ElementListType[T]]

class ElementList(list[ElementListType["ElementList"]]):
    pass

elements = ElementList(
    [
        Element(),
        Element(),
        [
            Element(),
            ElementList(
                [
                    Element(),
                    Element(),
                ]
            )
        ],
    ]
)

Demo with mypy here
Demo with pyright here
